# How to count the amount of prices python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-crawler, output

I was trying to crawl some prices from a webpage which I did successfully

```
prices = item.find_all("span", {"class": "price"})
for price in prices:
    price_end = price.text.strip().replace(",","")[2:]
    print(price_end)
```

The output is:

```
13
36
50
65
12
52
60
85
```

As a consequence I have 8 prices in total. My question, how can I automatically count with Python how many prices I got in the output?

I tried it with len  but it just gives me the length of the respective number.

It seems straight forward but I keep running into walls.

Could you guys help me out? Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
count = 0
prices = item.find_all("span", {"class": "price"})
for price in prices:
    price_end = price.text.strip().replace(",","")[2:]
    count += 1
    print(price_end)
print(count, " prices found")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. Does not lead to the desired result. I get the following result:                                                                                           1 prices found
1 prices found
1 prices found
1 prices found                                                                                                                              It does not sum up the amount of the prices. Any suggestions?:)

Comment: Check your indentation. The `print` should be outside the loop.

Comment: Its outside the loop but seems not to work. len(prices) does not work as well

Comment: Is there an outer loop we weren't shown? It looks like the print is inside some loop, since you're getting more than one.

Comment: Sorry, there was an outer loop that I forgot to mention. It works now. Thanks for your feedback and for your patience :)

Answer (score 1):

You could keep them in a list:

```
price_list=[]
prices = item.find_all("span", {"class": "price"})
for price in prices:
    price_end = price.text.strip().replace(",","")[2:]
    price_list.append(price_end)

print(len(price_list))
print('\n'.join(price_list))
```

(`len(prices)` might work too if you have one price for each entry...)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to store your prices in a list. Here's an alternative approach to using a for loop. This is called a list comprehension:

```
prices = [
    price.text.strip().replace(",","")[2:]
    for price in item.find_all("span", {"class": "price"})
]
```

This makes a list of prices. You can then print the number of prices and each price (here using string formatting):

```
print("{price_count} prices: {prices}".format(
    price_count=len(price_list)),
    prices=prices,
)
```